# adding horizontal splitter to my form

Tags: delphi

I have a grid along with some other controls inside a group box which is at top of the form, and I have another panel at the bottom of the form. I am creating a horizontal splitter in between the two. The group box alignment is set to `alTop`, the panel alignment is `alClient` and the splitter alignment is `alTop`.

I have set the `MinSize` of the splitter to `100` and that prevents the bottom panel from becoming invisible when I drag the splitter down. But when I drag it up, the upper groupbox becomes invisible at some point in time. Could you please help me to point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent the groupbox from disappearing just set its Constraints.MinHeight to the same value as the splitter MinSize. The splitter will snap the fixed control (groupbox) into its MinHeight value when the Height is below the MinSize.